# How can I sync up log times in logstash or kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have two logs from different sources that I am pulling into elasticsearch via logstash and then visualizing with kibana.  My problem is that the start time of each log should be the same however, one of the logs is recording entries incorrectly 30 minutes ahead.

How do I correct this time issue, is there a logstash filter that can subtract 30 minutes from the time or can I add some advanced query in Kibana?

I prefer to update the log entries in logstash.

Comment: Where does the dates come from? Parsed from the file or just the @timestamp added by logstash. Are you using one logstash or two? If two, are they on the same machine?

Comment: @baudsp the dates are coming from the logfiles themselves.  I'm just running one logstash over a couple of hours of each log file like a batch job, so I'm not running logstash continuously.

Comment: I've tried to find a way to change the value @timestamp field with the ruby filter but did not succeed, so I tried to see if the problem was coming from your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you may want to fix your logs so that the correct times are listed in the file. If your problem is in the data, it's easier to fix it there instead of wrestling with extra rules downstream.

But, you can manipulate the Logstash timestamp, if you need to.

The `@timestamp` field on each event has a lot in common with Ruby's `Time` class. In particular, it implements the same `+` and `-` operators which allow you to add or subtract some number of seconds:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
                event['@timestamp'] = LogStash::Timestamp.new(event['@timestamp'] + (30 * 60))
        "
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work with Logstash 2.2 : `Ruby exception occurred: The field '@timestamp' must be a (LogStash::Timestamp, not a Time`

Comment: Whoops. One thing I don't like about `ruby` filters is that they tend to be brittle between Logstash versions. I've edited the snippet so that it should work in 2.2

Comment: We don't know which version is used in this question, so your previous answer could have work as well. Anyway, your answer is better than mine, so I'll remove it. And I learned something, thank you.